# Flutter: obscureText, parameter not defined

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I recently started learning Flutter and I'm practicing by making an Instagram clone. I am trying to use 'obscureText' to hide the password but I receive an error: *The named parameter 'obscureText' isn't defined.*

I searched the web for a while but was unable to find a solution.

This is my first time posting here, if I missed something or placed this in the wrong section, please let me know.

Thanks! :)

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String _email, _password;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var symmetric;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Instagram',
              style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Billabong', fontSize: 50.0),
            ),
            Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 10.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
                        validator: (input) => !input.contains('@')
                            ? 'Please enter a valid email'
                            : null,
                        onSaved: (input) => _email = input),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 10.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                        validator: (input) => !input.contains('@')
                            ? 'Please enter a valid email'
                            : null,
                        onSaved: (input) => _email = input),
                    obscureText: true,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you defined the **obscureText** property out of the **TextFormField** widget. 
A right way would be:

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String _email, _password;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var symmetric;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Instagram',
              style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Billabong', fontSize: 50.0),
            ),
            Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 10.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
                        validator: (input) => !input.contains('@')
                            ? 'Please enter a valid email'
                            : null,
                        onSaved: (input) => _email = input),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 10.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      obscureText: true,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                      validator: (input) => !input.contains('@')
                            ? 'Please enter a valid email'
                            : null,
                        onSaved: (input) => _email = input),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey there @Angel Hernandez, welcome to the community!

I guess you have put obscureText outside the TextFormField.

```dart
Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 10.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                        validator: (input) => !input.contains('@')
                            ? 'Please enter a valid email'
                            : null,
                        onSaved: (input) => _email = input,
                        obscureText: true,) //TextFormField,
                  )//Padding,
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I spent so long thinking it was something more substantial.

Comment: Glad it helped !

Answer (score 0):

A small mistake you have made, obscureText: true is below TextFormField in your widget tree. It should be inside TextFormField.

Replace your Padding widget (wrapped around `InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password')`) with following code and it will start working:

```
Padding(
  padding:
      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 10.0),
  child: TextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
    validator: (input) => !input.contains('@')
        ? 'Please enter a valid email'
        : null,
    onSaved: (input) => _email = input,
    obscureText: true,
  ),
),
```